# Severe keyboard lag in Angular app on mobile Safari/Chrome

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, google-chrome, safari

I am experiencing a severe keyboard lag in an Angular app running on mobile Safari and Chrome. There is no lag of any sort when typing on desktop browsers. How could I go about troubleshooting this? I suspect it has to do with an overabundance of watchers on the page, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: Any chance we can see some of the code that is causing this lag?  I agree it probably has something to do with the watchers you have running.

Comment: I can't share it, unfortunately, but any general tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely correct that the number of watchers are slowing down your digest cycles.

To help with debugging this sort of performance, I have enjoyed using this tool to see in real time how many watchers you have running on a page: [ng-stats](https://github.com/kentcdodds/ng-stats)